# High-resolution GIS datasets of groundwave conductivity of the United States, besides the FCC?

Tags: geospatial

The FCC publishes a map of estimated groundwave conductivity of the United States, but the resolution is quite low:

[image: FCC groundwave conductivity map]

Are there any GIS datasets that include groundwave conductivity at a higher resolution and with more precision? I've already converted the map into a shapefile, so I don't just need the map in GIS format.